# Using dynamic linq extensions with jqgrid on one to many relationships

Tags: c#, linq, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Im not sure if the title of the question is correct if not let me know and i will change it. Okay so firstly im using jgrid in a asp.net application. I have a helper that sets up the page size, rows and does the sorting. The issue is i can only sort on parameters for the current table it does not work when the parameter name is from a separate table connected through a relationship.

The linq extension is for orderBy and thenBy, they both take a string parameter and sort order parameter. I have tried setting the string parameter as "WaterSample.Name", watersample being another table from a relationship and name a parameter in that table but unfortunately i cannot do it this way in c# since i am using an anonymous type. So my question is can i make the line extensions search through the relationships to find match the property name. Sorry if this is a bit confusing im still fairly new to linq.

i have included the class below that contains the extensions.

```
namespace Helpers
{
    [ModelBinder(typeof(GridModelBinder))]
    [Serializable]
    public class JqGridSettings
    {

        public int PageIndex { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public string SortColumn { get; set; }
        public string SortOrder { get; set; }
        public string SortColumn2 { get; set; }
        public string SortOrder2 { get; set; }
        public string SortColumn3 { get; set; }
        public string SortOrder3 { get; set; }

        public JqGridSettings()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the GridSettings class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringData">The string that represents the a GridSettings object.</param>
        public JqGridSettings(string stringData)
        {
            var tempArray = stringData.Split(new[] { "#;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            PageSize = int.Parse(tempArray[0]);
            PageIndex = int.Parse(tempArray[1]);
            SortColumn = tempArray[2];
            SortOrder = tempArray[3];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Build a string used to cache the current GridSettings object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A string that represents the current GridSettings object.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}#;{1}#;{2}#;{3}", PageSize, PageIndex, SortColumn,SortOrder);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> LoadGridData<T>(IQueryable<T> dataSource, out int count)
        {
            var query = dataSource;
            //
            // Sorting and Paging by using the current grid settings.
            //
            query = query.OrderBy<T>(SortColumn, SortOrder);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn2) == false)
            {
                query = query.ThenBy<T>(SortColumn2, SortOrder2);
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn3) == false)
            {
                query = query.ThenBy<T>(SortColumn3, SortOrder3);
            }
            count = query.Count();
            //
            if (PageIndex < 1)
                PageIndex = 1;
            //
            var data = query.Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction)
        {
            var methodName = string.Format("OrderBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");
            var memberAccess = sortColumn.Split('.').Aggregate<string, MemberExpression>(null, (current, property) => Expression.Property(current ?? (parameter as Expression), property));

            var orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);
            var result = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),methodName,new[]{query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type},query.Expression,Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));

            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
        }

        public static IQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction)
        {
            var methodName = string.Format("ThenBy{0}", direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");
            var memberAccess = sortColumn.Split('.').Aggregate<string, MemberExpression>(null, (current, property) => Expression.Property(current ?? (parameter as Expression), property));

            var orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);
            var result = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type }, query.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));

            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
        }
    }

    public class GridModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
                return new JqGridSettings
                {
                    PageIndex = int.Parse(request["page"] ?? "1"),
                    PageSize = int.Parse(request["rows"] ?? "50"),
                    SortColumn = request["sidx"] ?? "",
                    SortOrder = request["sord"] ?? "asc",
                };
            }
            catch
            {
                //
                // For unexpected errors use the default settings!
                //
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: How many total rows exist in the dataset which you need to display (<100, <1000, <10000, >1000000, ...)? The problem is that one uses frequently *server side paging*, sorting and filtering for small set of data, which require long code and works slowly as the usage of `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options and *client side* paging, sorting and filtering. The server code will be very simple in the case. If you really need server side paging, then the usage of Entity Framework methods `.Skip` and `.Top` could simplify your code.

Comment: the dataset will be growing so it will become quite large. And unfortunately we dont use Entity Framework.

Comment: What you use then instead of Entity Framework?

Comment: As far as i know we just use linq. The filtering works fine, and sorting works if the property is part of the current table. but if im displaying information through a relationship the sorting does not work. It would be nice if the orderBy extension could check the properties on tables linked to the current one through a relationship then sorting would always work for me.

Comment: LINQ don't contains sorting by string as parameter. It's a real disadvantage of LINQ. There are exist extension which allows that do this. For example LINQ Dynamic Query Library see http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/, https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic, https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/. Read http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/07/16/Dynamic-LINQ-Using-strings-to-sort-by-properties-and-child-object-properties.aspx fo example

Comment: In general, LINQ Dynamic Query Library does the same like you: use Expression.Lambda. If you knows the names of all columns then you can just write simple switch, where you test for the name of every column and use orderby directly by the property name. I personally find the usage of LINQ for the wrong way for dynamic queries.

Comment: Yer i was thinking i would have to resort to a switch, i was hoping id be able to do it without and keep it a bit cleaner. I am tied into link unfortunately working on a large application that i didn't create. Thank you for your help i will have a look at the dynamic link.